# CPU gap when doing k-means with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, k-means

- I am working with Spark 1.2.0.
- My feature vector is about 350 dimensions
- The data set is about 24k vectors
- **The problem I described below only happens to `kmeans||` algorithm;** I have switched to `kmeans-random` for now, but I would like to know why `kmeans||` doesn't work.

When I call `KMeans.train` with **k=100**, I observe this CPU usage gap after Spark has done several `collectAsMap` calls. As I marked in the red in the image, there are 8 cores, only 1 core is working while the other 7 are at rest during this *gap*.

If I raise k to 200, the gap will significantly increase.

**I want to know why this gap? How to avoid it?** Because my work requires me to set **k=5000** with a much larger data set. With my current settings, the job never ends...

I have tried my approach with both Windows and Linux (both are 64bit) environment, and I observe the same behavior.

*I you want, I could give you the code and sample data.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [SPARK-3220](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3220) for detail about this issue.

In summary, it is because the default *kmeans||* initialize process is not distributed and it is performed on the *driver* with a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the WebUI, especially GC times? One CPU up, all others down could be a stop-the-world garbage collection.

You might wanna try enabling parallel GC and check the section on GC tuning in the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning).

Other than that, `collectAsMap` return the data to the master/driver, so the bigger the data gets, the longer the single driver process will take to process. You should also try increasing `spark.driver.memory`.

Comment: +1. I would like emphasize on the fact that `collectAsMap` returns the data to the master/driver. This could be the root of your *problem*, although it's an implementation issue, more than an actual problem.

Comment: `collectAsMap` is called inside the `KMeans` algorithm, I cannot control that.

Comment: I have checked the GC, the executor & driver memory. Everything looks fine. This problem only happens if I use the `kmeans||` algorithm.

Comment: As Mikel suggested, this might not be a problem, but just the way the algorithm works.